# Strange behavior of preg_match_all php

Tags: php, regex

I have a very long string of html. From this string I want to parse pairs of rus and eng names of cities. Example of this string is:

$html =   '
                            [Абакан](/forecasts5000/russia/republic-khakassia/abakan)
                            
                            Хакасия республика
                        
                        
                            [Абан](/forecasts5000/russia/krasnoyarsk-territory/aban)
                            
                            Красноярский край
                        
                        
                            [Абатский](/forecasts5000/russia/tyumen-area/abatskij)
                            
                            Тюменская область
                        ';

My code is:

```
$subject = $this->html;
$pattern = '/<a href="([\/a-zA-Z0-9-"]*)">([а-яА-Я]*)/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
```

For trying I use regexer . You can see it here http://regexr.com/399co
On the test used global modifier - /g
Because of in PHP we can't use /g modifier I use preg_match_all function. But result of preg_match_all is very strange:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <a href="/forecasts5000/russia/republic-khakassia/abakan">Абакан
            [1] => <a href="/forecasts5000/russia/krasnoyarsk-territory/aban">Абан
            [2] => <a href="/forecasts5000/russia/tyumen-area/abatskij">Аба�
            [3] => <a href="/forecasts5000/russia/arkhangelsk-area/abramovskij-ma">Аб�
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => /forecasts5000/russia/republic-khakassia/abakan
            [1] => /forecasts5000/russia/krasnoyarsk-territory/aban
            [2] => /forecasts5000/russia/tyumen-area/abatskij
            [3] => /forecasts5000/russia/arkhangelsk-area/abramovskij-ma
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Абакан
            [1] => Абан
            [2] => Аба�
            [3] => Аб�
        )

)
```

First of all - it found only first match (but I need to get array with all matches)
The second - result is very strange for me. I want to get the next result:
pairs of /forecasts5000/russia/republic-khakassia/abakan and Абакан
 What do I do wrong?

Comment: Please show your __actual__ PHP code.

Comment: This is exactly what I'd expect to see, what are you expecting?

Comment: 2 hjpotter92: added a code

Comment: 2 scragar: added a information about what I expect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Element 0 of the result is an array of each of the full matches of the regexp. Element 1 is an array of all the matches for capture group 1, element 2 contains capture group 2, and so on.

You can invert this by using the `PREG_SET_ORDER` flag. Then element 0 will contain all the results from the first match, element 1 will contain all the results from the second match, and so on. Within each of these, `[0]` will be the full match, and the remaining elements will be the capture groups.

If you use this option, you can then get the information you want with:

```
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $url = $match[1];
    $text = $match[2];
    // Do something with $url and $text
}
```

Comment: I tried add this flag but it's sort only my result not change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [T-Regx library](https://t-regx.com) which has separate methods for each case :)

```
pattern('<a href="([/a-zA-Z0-9-"]*)">([а-яА-Я]*)')
  ->match($this->html)
  ->forEach(function (Match $match) {
      $match = $match->text();
      $group = $match->group(1);
      echo "Match $match with group $group"
  });
```

I also has automatic delimiters